# How to get n-th attribute of class in C++

Tags: c++, templates

With a normal class. For example:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
    std::string b;
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
}
```

We can do:

```
A x;
x.a = 1;
x.b = "hello";
```

But now I don't want to do like above. I want to access n_index-th attribute of object. For example pseudo like `x.get<2>()` (or `x.set<2>(...)`) like `x.b`.
How can do that? Have any template for that.
Beside if I want code like that

```
int number = 2;
x.get<number>()
```

Any problem with `constexpr`?

Comment: You can store your members in a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) if you want to access your members by index.

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism in C++ that would let you convert an integer index of a field into a reference to a member variable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ..but you aren't going to get them even with a tuple with run-time index value calculation.

Comment: maybe you could create an array of std::any?

Comment: @WhozCraig if my solution covered everything asked in the question, I would have made it an answer.

Comment: If you want to set several values at the same time, you should make a constructor with several parameters. But no, there is no ready-made way of doing this. You could do it yourself, however this would be very bug-prone : What if you reorder your attributes? Then you will have to rework a **lot** your code.

Comment: @OP does this need to be a run time or compile time solution?

Comment: @AnthonyD. I hope will have good solution for my question and reorder attributes.

Comment: The important question here is why you would want to do this. While the attributes do have an order within a class, this order should not be ever relevant. What you want hurts both type safety and encapsulation. And the basic concept of a class, which should not be simply seen as a data holder (in general). Therefore, why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve in the big picture? And if you really have a valid reason, why not go with a vector over a union (which would still be very very ugly, plus I have no idea how you would decide what type of variable you got for the indices)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set several values at the same time when you create the object, you could use a multi-parameter constructor. For example, let's imagine you have this:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
    std::string b;
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
};
```

You could add a constructor that sets `a` and `b`:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
    std::string b;

    A() {}

    A(int a, std::string b) {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }

    ~A() {}
};
```

That way, you can create your object *and* set `a` and `b` with :

```
A a = A(1, "hello");
```

There is no ready-made way of setting the n-th attribute of your object. You could make one, but I would ***very, very highly*** recommend that you don't. Like I said above, if you reorder your attributes, then you will have to rework everything.

If you really, *really* want to make your life very, very, very much harder, a very ugly and error-prone way of doing this would be like :

```
template<class T>
void A::setNth(int nth, const T& value) {
    switch (nth) {
    case 1: a = value; break;
    case 2: b = value; break;
     // You should #include <stdexcept> to use runtime_error, or you could handle the exception in some other way.
    default: throw std::runtime_error("A::setNthAttribute : Value of nth is out of bounds.");
    }
}
```

For the getter:

```
template<class T>
void A::getNth(int nth, T& valueOut) {
    switch (nth) {
    case 1: valueOut = a; break;
    case 2: valueOut = b; break;
    default: throw std::runtime_error("A::getNthAttribute : Value of nth is out of bounds.");
    }
}
```

You would use these methods like this:

```
A a;

a.setNth(1, 2); // put 2 into a

int i;
a.getNth(1, i); // put a into i
```

Just writing this code send shivers down my spine. Please, never write what I just wrote. ***Chuck Norris will kill yoU agfh
86sd asdsa dDASD8!4.***

Comment: Way better than my ridiculous solution. +1.

Comment: @JeremiahB That comment made me giggle. +1 for your good spirit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get is using [boost::fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/).

An example would be

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int a;
    std::string b;
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(A,
  (int, a)
  (std::string, b)
)

using namespace boost::fusion;

int main()
{
    A x;
    x.a = 1;
    x.b = "hello";
    std::cout << at<boost::mpl::int_<0>>(x) << '\n';
    std::cout << at<boost::mpl::int_<1>>(x) << '\n';

    at<boost::mpl::int_<0>>(x) = 5;
    at<boost::mpl::int_<1>>(x) = std::string("World");

    std::cout << at<boost::mpl::int_<0>>(x) << '\n';
    std::cout << at<boost::mpl::int_<1>>(x) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: :( now i'm not allowed use boost

Comment: @TrungTrinh: You should have mentioned that in your question. But maybe the boost lib gives you a hint how to solve your problem.

Comment: i will check boost::fusion :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are considering is in fact possible, but a bit of a headache.  I would approach it by creating a template getter and setter for every member that one can set or get, and then having a template method that takes an int and sets or gets the appropriate property.  The getters/setters would have to be specialized for the correct type, and throw an error for other types. This method would have to use a switch to return the right member:

```
   class bar {
   private:
      int a;
      std::string b;
      template<T>
      T getA() {
         // error
      }
      template<T>
      T getB() {
        // error
      }
      template<T>
      void setA(const T& A) {
         // error
      }
      template<T>
      void setB(const T& B) {
          // error
      }
      template <> std::string getB(); // specialization
      template <> int getA();
      template <> void setB(const std::string&);
      template <> void setA(int);
   public:
      template<T>
      T get(int what) {
             switch(what) {
                case 1:
                   return getA();
                case 2:
                   return getB();
                default:
                   // handle error here
                   break;
             }
         }
      template<T>
      void set(int what, const T& t) {
             switch(what) {
                case 1:
                   return setA<T>(t);
                case 2:
                   return setB<T>(t);
                default:
                   // handle error here
                   break;
             }
         }
    };



    bar b;

    b.set<std::string>(2, "foo");
    auto str = b.get<std::string>(2);
```

Comment: That won't work. You cannot have different return types based on a `switch` statement.

Comment: I realised that immediately after posting and am working on it some more.  Thanks!

Comment: your solution get error, because of when you use switch case

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elaborate way to accomplish what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// A namespace explicitly defined for class A.
namespace A_NS
{
   // A template for members of A.
   template <int> struct Member;

   // Specialization for the first member.
   template <> struct Member<1>
   {
      using type = int;
      type var;
   };

   // Specialization for the second member.
   template <> struct Member<2>
   {
      using type = std::string;
      type var;
   };
}

class A {
   public:

      A() {}
      ~A() {}

      template <int N> typename A_NS::Member<N>::type get() const
      {
         return static_cast<A_NS::Member<N> const&>(members).var;
      }

      template <int N> void set(typename A_NS::Member<N>::type const& in)
      {
         static_cast<A_NS::Member<N>&>(members).var = in;
      }

   private:

      // Define a type for the member variables.
      struct Members : A_NS::Member<1>, A_NS::Member<2> {};

      // The member variables.
      Members members;
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   a.set<1>(10);
   a.set<2>("test");

   std::cout << a.get<1>() << ", " << a.get<2>() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
10, test
```

Comment: @R Sahu: about constexpr, Do you have any solution?

Comment: When you have a `std::string` as a member, you can't use `constexpr`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType.

Comment: @R Sahu: I mean x.get<number>() or any type equivalent

Comment: @TrungTrinh, I didn't understand that.